# Hiding types in different layers using Ninject

Tags: ninject

I have a class that Ninject injects dependencies in to. One of the injected types lives in a different assembly to Ninject. I have the module registered in Assembly1 however.

```
/*Assembly1.Dll (Logical layer)*/
internal class InternalType {}

public class Gobblin {

  InternalType _iType;

  internal Gobblin(InternalType iType) {
    _iType = iType;
  }
}

public class CommonModule : NinjectModule {

  public override void Load() {

    Bind<IInternalType>()
         .To<InternalType>()
         .InRequestScope();
  }

}
/*End assembly1 code*/
```

My other assembly is a MVC web application. One of my controllers needs the Gobblin class but the binding is failing due to no constructors being found by Ninject.

I understand that Ninject has no access to the internal constructor of the Gobblin class, but I assumed because the module that registered it was contained in the same assembly it would have worked.

I could just break OO principles here and make the InternalType public, but I want to know if there's another way first.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assembly is external to Ninject itself. The default configuration does not allow injection of none public constructors, properties, ... You can change the configuration though. Have a look at NinjectSettings.